# SQL merge rows as columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have some findings with lab values. Is it possible to create an sql statement, which results dynamically in the following? I would like to create a view with every finding (res/printdate) as one/two columns.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Dynamically could be tricky as the number of columns you be pivoting to can go to n... am I right? Or do you have the maximum number of pivots in mind?  If you know how many columns you may want to pivot upfront I guess such code can be written

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It is possible to get the number of findings, like 5.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: sorry, I have edited the tags. It's oracle.

Comment: Please add the expected result set for all the ids `AMY and AP` . Hope you want to group by `id` column. you do not need `res` column?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use the old school way : using windows function -

Rownum over partition by

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-row_number/

Assuming your table is called Lab_Result

Add a new column called RowNum

```
Create View Lab_Result_W_Row as
    select
       LR.*,
       Row_number() over(partition_by id, order by printdate) Row_Num
    from 
     Lab_Result LR;
```

Traverse the result

```
select
    R1.id,
    R1.uni,
    R1.rpsrange,
    R1.val as Val1,
    R1.Printdate as printdate1,
    R2.Val as Val2
    R2.Printdate as Printdate2
from
   Lab_Result_W_Row R1
   left join Lab_Result_W_Row  R2 on
      R1.id =R2.id
   and
      Row2.Row_num = 2
Where
     R1.Row_num =1
```

You can still use the pivot function to get the job done. But you still need to have the row_num column